# Why does Visual Studio Community 2022 compile my c++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

In my program, I have the following code, and somehow it compiles, but it shouldn't.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::list<int> collection = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    for each (auto i in collection)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got this code from auto-completion:

`for each (auto item in collection)`

I use the following command in the Developer Powershell to compile my code:

`cl /EHsc /std:c++17 .\programm.cpp`

Please help me. I have no idea why this happens, and when I am trying to search for it on the Internet, all I find are problems where it doesn't compile.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you certain you saved the file with the supposed error in it before compiling? Are you sure it's the same file?

Answer (score 5):

A `for each` loop is a Microsoft-specific extension to the C++ language:

[`for each`, `in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=msvc-170)

> Iterates through an array or collection. This non-standard keyword is available in both C++/CLI and native C++ projects. However, its use isn't recommended. Consider using a standard [Range-based for Statement (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/range-based-for-statement-cpp?view=msvc-170) instead.
>
> ...
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> for each ( type identifier in expression ) {
>   statements
> }
> ```

That is why the code compiles in Visual Studio.  It will not compile in any other C++ compiler.

Comment: Is there a way to deactivate that?

Comment: @anonymous It doesn't seem to work in `/permissive-` (or `/std:c++20` or later) mode, which would anyway be recommended if you want to make sure you are writing standard conforming code.

Comment: @anonymous why do you need to *deactivate* it? Simply don't use it in your code, just use a standard `range-for` loop instead, like the documentation says, eg: `for (auto i : collection)`

Comment: I need to deactivate it because I lost points for my homework from it and since I don't know what other functions might exist because of the same thing I want to deactivate it to not loose points because of any other functions in the future.

Comment: @anonymous sounds like maybe you should turn off auto-completion entirely, and just manually write code for things you have actually learned so far.